# Extract sub-project from big project in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a *BIG* project in IDEA (basically the trunk of my company source code), but I need to work only on one of the "modules" (not sure how to call those). Is there a way I could export/create from/in IDEA a smaller project with the part of trunk I'm interested in? It's pretty self-contained, there should be dependencies only on 1 or 2 other projects in trunk.

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic option to extract a part of a project. You should create a new project from the existing sources, it will contain only required modules with content roots set to the parts of the bigger project and [dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) configured between them.